# Dockerfile for GPU and non-GPU versions

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gpu, nvidia-docker

I have a project that I maintain using Dockerfile. It is a data science project so and the docker can be used in many environments, local, in the cloud, with or without GPU.

The difference between the GPU and the non-GPU version is very small, just this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04  -> non-GPU
FROM nvidia/cuda   -> GPU
```

What is the best way to handle this scenario?

P.S: I am using docker-compose to build the docker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple docker files inside your docker-compose yml file as below,

```
├── docker-compose.yml
├── GPU project
│   └── GPU.Dockerfile
└── NON-GPU project
    └── NONGPU.Dockerfile
```

Also it's possible to get syntax highlighting in VS code by giving files .Dockerfile extension(instead of name) e.g. GPU.Dockerfile, NONGPU.Dockerfile etc.

Comment: Seems like a good solution. Is there a way to build just one of these "sub-projects"?

Comment: As per the docker file build configuration, https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build 
you can use dockerfile: Dockerfile-alternate inside of the build section for your container to choose which docker file you need. 

Also you can find docker compose build commands here too
https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr/blob/master/pages/common/docker-compose.md
And the official documentation is https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I needed, thank you very much!